# Spring JavaMailSender: Making it asynchronous and persistent

Tags: spring, queue, jms, spring-jms

Is there an easy/lightweight way to add persistence to Spring's JavaMailSender and have it operate asynchronously? Does Spring provide any "built-in" support for this? I'm currently looking at queues with JMS, but they seem like overkill for the task at hand (looking at ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ). Is there a lightweight JMS option?

Comment: What do you mean by "persistence"?

Comment: @skaffman surviving a server restart.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with [jms](/questions/tagged/jms) is fine. Unfortunately persistence and asynchronous processing is not such a simple task and you will have to code a bit.

However have a look at [Spring integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration), it provides built-in support for JMS inbounds and e-mail outbounds - all you have to do is connect the pieces via XML DSL.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make any method in Spring asynchronous, all you need to do is configure `task` namespace in the xml config via `<task:annotation-driven/>`.  Then, you just annotate the method with `@Async` and it will run in its own thread.  Note that an async call will run in its own transaction, as Spring grabs a new thread from its internal pool to service the call.  If you do this, then you don't need JMS for aynchronous processing.